# How to get values from DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-alertdialog

I can't manage to figure out how to use the values within my onClick Method. I have this Class with an onCreateDialog method that prompts the user to input the following [User is prompted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT19s.png)

Here is the code

```
public class InfoPrompt extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
private EditText editTextTitle;
private EditText editTextAuthor;
private EditText editTextPageCount;
private EditText editTextDeadline;
//private InfoPromptListener listener;


@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_prompt, null);

    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setTitle("Add Work");
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            String bookTitle = editTextTitle.getText().toString();
            String bookAuthor = editTextAuthor.getText().toString();

            String pageCount = editTextPageCount.getText().toString();
            Long pageCountLong = Long.parseLong(pageCount);

            String deadline = editTextDeadline.getText().toString();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date deadlineDate = null;
            try {
                deadlineDate = sdf.parse(deadline);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
            Long daysBetweenDates = currentDate.getTime() - deadlineDate.getTime();
            Long pagesPerDay = pageCountLong / daysBetweenDates;
            //listener.applyTexts(bookTitle,bookAuthor,pageCountLong,deadline,daysBetweenDates,pagesPerDay);



        }

    });
    editTextTitle = view.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
    editTextAuthor = view.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
    editTextPageCount = view.findViewById(R.id.pageCount);
    editTextDeadline = view.findViewById(R.id.deadline);

    return builder.create();
}
```

I've set the different strings being equal to the input in the editText but I don't know how I would access these variables

I need to use them in another class when inflating another layout with these values.

I was thinking something along these lines

```
private void applyTexts(String bookTitle, String bookAuthor, Long pageCountLong, String deadline, Long daysBetweenDates, Long pagesPerDay) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_work, null, false);

    TextView bookTitleTV = view.findViewById(R.id.bookTitle);
    TextView bookAuthorTV = view.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
    BubbleSeekBar seekBarBSB = view.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    TextView deadlineTV = view.findViewById(R.id.deadline);
    TextView pagesLeftTV = view.findViewById(R.id.pagesLeft);
    TextView todayReadTV = view.findViewById(R.id.todayRead);

    bookTitleTV.setText(bookTitle);
    bookAuthorTV.setText(bookAuthor);
    seekBarBSB.setProgress(pageCountLong);
    deadlineTV.setText(deadline);

    int getProgress = seekBarBSB.getProgress();
    Long pagesLeftLong = pageCountLong-getProgress;
    String pagesLeftString = Long.toString(pagesLeftLong);
    pagesLeftTV.setText(pagesLeftString);

    String ppd = Long.toString(pagesLeftLong/daysBetweenDates);
    todayReadTV.setText(ppd);

    thisLayout.addView(view);
```

. I have little experience with android development so a lot of things might not make sense but all help is appreciated

Comment: Are you trying to send result back to some Activity/Fragment/ViewModel from your Dialog?

Comment: I want to take the information from the edit text of the Dialog and pass it on to another function that inflates a view where i need these information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting info from an EditText:

```
String userInput = editText.getText().toString().trim()
if (!userInput.isEmpty()) {
    anotherFunctionThatNeedsThisInfo(userInput);
}
```

```
private void anotherFunctionThatNeedsThisInfo(String userInput) {
    //Do what you need with the data
    String welcomeText = "Hello, your input is: " + userInput;
}
```

You need to get every `EditText` input separately.

We use `trim()` to remove blank spaces that users may have accidentally added to the input.

Check user input for not being empty inside the if statement. `!isEpmty()` checks it is not empty.

EditText never returns null, it only returns empty if no user input is added.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The isEmpty function will definitely be put to use, but my issue isn't getting the information. It's that i can't seem to use it in other funcitons. if you could showcase an example of how you'd use this "userInput" in another function that would be apreciated :)

Comment: @RasmusAndersen I edited my answer If it didn't help Please edit your question and remove extra code snippets.  It's not really clear what you want to achieve.